# Golang mux router handler function arguments

Tags: go, mux

I was trying to set up a CRUD http API using gorilla-mux library.

I followed a youtube tutorial 
Implementation is below: -

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "net/http"
    "log"
)

type Book struct {
    Id     string  `json:"id"`
    Isbn   string  `json:"isbn"`
    Title  string  `json:"title"`
    Author *Author `json:"author"`
}

type Author struct {
    Firstname string `json:"firstname"`
    Lastname  string `json:"lastname"`
}

// Get all books
func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}

// Get single book
func getBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}

// Create a book
func createBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}

// Update a book
func updateBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}

// Delete a book
func deleteBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.HandleFunc("/api/books", getBooks).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/book/{id}", getBook).Methods("GET")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/book", createBook).Methods("POST")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/book/{id}", updateBook).Methods("PUT")
    r.HandleFunc("/api/book/{id}", deleteBook).Methods("DELETE")

    r.Path("/api/books").Methods("GET").HandlerFunc(getBooks)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

When I do go build on this file, I get below compilation errors -

> ./main.go:49:15: cannot use getBooks (type func(http.ResponseWriter,
>   *http.Response)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to r.HandleFunc ./main.go:50:15: cannot use getBook (type
>   func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Response)) as type
>   func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to r.HandleFunc
>   ./main.go:51:15: cannot use createBook (type func(http.ResponseWriter,
>   *http.Response)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to r.HandleFunc ./main.go:52:15: cannot use updateBook (type
>   func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Response)) as type
>   func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to r.HandleFunc
>   ./main.go:53:15: cannot use deleteBook (type func(http.ResponseWriter,
>   *http.Response)) as type func(http.ResponseWriter, *http.Request) in argument to r.HandleFunc

What did I do wrong? What did I miss here? In the tutorial, he was able to build and run the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HanldeFunc type of function takes two paramters you are passing it wrong.

```
// Get all books
func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Response) {

}
```

It should be `*http.Request` not `*http.Response`

```
// Get all books
func getBooks(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

}
```

Checkout on [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/dLZqICbjC54)

Comment: Whoops!! Very silly mistake. As you pointed out, it needs to be `*http.Request`. So they say, sometimes it is better-off not using code hinting :). Thanks a lot.

Comment: And, Thank you for such a quick response.

Comment: Actually `HandleFunc` type of functions always have inbuilt `handlers` which you can create using ServeHttp too